# Can you animate a <abbr> title in CSS?

Tags: html, css, title

Can you make the title of an `<abbr>` element fade in with CSS?
I know how to style the title and i was wondering if it is possible to animate it as well.
I mean, when you hover over the  element, it suddenly appears. I want it to slowly fade in and was wondering if it was possible in CSS. 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MisterHappy/4qFB8/)

```
<abbr title="I want this to fade in">Hover over Me!</abbr>
```

```
abbr {
    position: relative;
    border:none;
}
abbr:hover::after {
    position: absolute;
    height:auto;
    width:475px;
    bottom: -50px;
    color:black !important;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    background: gold;
    border-radius:2px;
    content: attr(title);
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a value where transition is numbers : `opacity` for instance. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4qFB8/2/)**

```
abbr:hover::after {
    opacity:1;
}
abbr::after {
    position: absolute;
    opacity:0;
    height:auto;
    width:475px;
    bottom: -50px;
    color:black !important;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    background: gold;
    border-radius:2px;
    content: attr(title);
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:1s;/* DO NOT FORGET THE REGULAR ONE */
    }
```

In the demo, pseudo already exists but is translucide untill you hover `<abbr>`

Comment: Thank you! I accidentally forgot the regular one, Sorry! ;)

Comment: Just to add that from what I remember some browsers had problems transitioning pseudo elements(::after), not sure if the situation has changed

Comment: @crisbeto ::after is not understood by IE8, but :after does :)